# WPF DropDownButton IsOpen binding breaks after opening drop down

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have come across a peculiar issue I have had trouble fixing. Below is simplified code that shows the problem.

I have a WPF DropDownButton that contains a list of strings in it's drop down. I also have a search box. The idea being as you type in the search box, the drop down automatically expands and shows only the matching items (thus making it easier for you to find the one you are interested in). If there are no matching items or the search field is empty the drop down is closed. If there is a search term but no matching items the search field changes colour.

All this works fine. Until that is, you either clear the search field (when there was something to clear) using it's button or drop down the list using it's drop down arrow button. Once you do either of these the drop down no longer automatically opens and closes as you change the search term.

Once it is 'broken' the searching still works in that you can search for something e.g. 'Text 1' and if you open the drop down list it contains only the matching items. It is just the automatic opening and closing that no longer works.

I have checked and the ViewModel is raising the correct events. I have looked in to the DropDownButton code and can see it when it works the `OnIsOpenChanged` code is reached, but once broken it doesn't.

Could it be that by 'manually' opening the drop down I break/overwrite the `IsOpen` binding? If so how can I work round this. And why does clearing the search field break the binding as well? Removing the manual dropdown aspect is not an option.

**EDIT**
In the button click code behind (which I have tried replacing with a command but it make no difference to the behaviour) after setting the `SeachExpression` I added:

```
 BindingExpression be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(SelectButton, Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DropDownButton.IsOpenProperty);
```

which I think is the correct way to check if there is a binding and it comes back null. If I do this before setting the `SeachExpression` it is non-null.

*ViewModel*

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private IList<string> originalText;

    public string SearchExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchExpression;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == _searchExpression)
                return;

            _searchExpression = value;
            UpdateDescriptions(_searchExpression);
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchExpression");
        }
    }
    string _searchExpression = string.Empty;

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Descriptions
    {
        get { return _descriptions; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == _descriptions)
                return;

            _descriptions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Descriptions");
        }
    }
    ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> _descriptions;

    public bool NoMatches 
    {
        get { return _noMatches; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == _noMatches)
                return;

            _noMatches = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NoMatches");
        }
    }
    bool _noMatches;

    public bool ShowSearchResults
    {
        get { return _showSearchResults; }
        private set
        {
            if (value == _showSearchResults)
                return;

            _showSearchResults = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShowSearchResults");
        }
    }
    bool _showSearchResults;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        originalText = new List<string>() {"Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"};
        UpdateDescriptions();
    }

    private void UpdateDescriptions(string searchExpression = null)
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> descriptions = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        IEnumerable<string> records;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchExpression))
        {
            records = originalText;
            NoMatches = false;
            ShowSearchResults = false;
        }
        else
        {
            records = originalText.Where(x => x.Contains(searchExpression));
            NoMatches = records.Count() < 1;
            ShowSearchResults = records.Count() > 0;
        }

        descriptions = new ObservableCollection<string>(records);

        this.Descriptions = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(descriptions);
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

*View*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=WPFToolkit.Extended"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="65" Width="225">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <wpf:DropDownButton Grid.Column="0" x:Name="SelectButton" Content="Select" Margin="3 0" IsOpen="{Binding ShowSearchResults, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <wpf:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            <ListBox x:Name="descriptionsList" MaxHeight="250" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Descriptions, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

                <!-- this code makes sure the ListBox displays at the correct with for the outset, and does not resize as you scroll-->
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </wpf:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
    </wpf:DropDownButton>

    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="searchTextBox" Text="{Binding SearchExpression, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Watermark="Search" ToolTip="Search for an item in the list." >
                <xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NoMatches}" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Tomato"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBox.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </xctk:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
            </xctk:WatermarkTextBox>

            <Button Grid.Column="1"  
                x:Name="ClearButton"
                ToolTip="Clear search text"
                Click="ClearButton_Click" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="/WPFToolkit.Extended;component/PropertyGrid/Images/ClearFilter16.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

View Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
            vm.SearchExpression = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: For first  - bind the Click event on ClearButton to  the ViewModel command and clear the data there. Second  - string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchExpression) - probably should be string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExpression) or change vm.SearchExpression = string.Empty

Comment: @VitaliyK I tried binding the click event to a command rather than code behind makes no difference. As do the other suggestions. I've updated the original description to state that once the IsOpen is broken the search still works in that you can search for something and if you manually open the drop down it is reduce to just those matching entries

Comment: while i'm checking the source, i found , they have set IsOpen directly at some places. Can you try to replace those lines with SetValue(IsOpenProperty,true/false) in their source and check?

Comment: @WPFUser I'm not sure if I've understood you correctly, but I could only find one place where IsOpen is set directly, to `false` (in DropDownButton.cs `CloseDropDown()`), changing it there to `SetValue(IsOpenProperty, false)` as you suggested did not change the behaviour.

Comment: @B_D yes that is what i meant, and what about the IsOpen set at OnKeyDown ?

Comment: @WPFUser I don't set IsOpen on keydown, at least not directly. I set a property (`ShowSearchResults`) it binds to. And that works fine until I click on the dropdownbutton to open the dropdown 'manually', after that it seems the binding no longer works. I was wondering if doing it manually resets/clears the binding.

Comment: @B_D not sure why this issue occuring, but if you comment Popup_Opened method in DropDownButton.cs file, you will get rid of this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130792/discussion-between-b-d-and-wpfuser).